# OrientDB HTTP REST Api Query Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, http, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm getting a 401 unauthorized error on my `api` request. It works for every other `api` endpoints(connect, server, class) just not the query endpoint. Does anyone know if additional parameters were needed for authorization?

```
      fetch(
           'http://localhost:2480/class/query/DB/sql/'+'Select from Results',
           {
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.encode('admin'+":"+'admin')},
            }
       ).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res)
            return res;
       })
```

> Error:
>    {[{code: 401, reason: "Unauthorized", content: "401    Unauthorized."}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either "[query](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html#query)" or "[class](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html#class)" to get informations about a class:

```
http://localhost:2480/query/DB/sql/Select from Results
```

```
http://localhost:2480/class/DB/Results
```

Keep in mind you can only make GET requests with the "query" command.

Comment: Aww fudge, I didn't see the extra '/class', thanks for pointing it out!